# Passport authorization callback redirects to beginning (Box)

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm attempting to authenticate a user using Box.com OAuth2.0. I make the initial call and login which redirects to my callback url with the authorization code. At this point my server handles the callback using passport but for some reason it returns a 302 and redirects to the beginning of the oauth authentication process.

```
  //box authentication routes
  app.get('/api/box', passport.authorize('box'));

  // the callback after box has authorized the user
  app.get('/api/box/callback', passport.authorize('box', {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/login'
    })
  );
```

I verified that my route is being called by using my own handler and the request data seems to be correct. Box returns a 200 and the url contains the authorization code.

```
app.get('/api/box/callback', function(req, res) {
    console.log('auth called')
  });
```

This is my passport strategy:

```
passport.use(new BoxStrategy({
    clientID: config.box.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.box.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.box.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    process.nextTick(function() {

      if(!req.user) {
          // try to find the user based on their google id
        User.findOne({ 'box.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {
          if (err)
            return done(err);

          if (user) {
            // if a user is found, log them in
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            // if the user isnt in our database, create a new user
            var newUser = new User();

            // set all of the relevant information
            newUser.box.id = profile.id;
            newUser.box.accessToken = accessToken;
            newUser.box.refreshToken = refreshToken;
            newUser.box.name  = profile.name;
            newUser.box.email = profile.login;

            // save the user
            newUser.save(function(err) {
              if (err)
                throw err;
              return done(null, newUser);
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        // user already exists and is logged in, we have to link accounts
        var user = req.user;

        // update the current users box credentials
        user.box.id = profile.id;
        user.box.accessToken = accessToken;
        user.box.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        user.box.name  = profile.name;
        user.box.email = profile.login;

        // save the user
        user.save(function(err) {
          if (err)
            throw err;
          return done(null, user);
        });
      }
    });
  }
));
```

Would appreciate any insight as to what might be causing this redirect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being an instance of PeerServer that was somehow causing the redirect.